# Positioning of pause and play buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pause").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#play").show();
        $("#aa").stop(true, false);
        audioTag1.pause();
    });
    $("#play").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#pause").show();
        animateaa();
    });
});
```

---

*html*

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 670px; bottom: 45px;">
    <div id="pause" onClick="pause.style.visibility= 'hidden'; play.style.visibility= 'visible';"></div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 665px; bottom: 45px;">
    <div id="play" onClick="play.style.visibility= 'hidden'; pause.style.visibility= 'visible';"></div>
</div>
```

The above code I have used for the functionality pause and play, which is working fine. Now I need to achieve the same by placing those buttons one on top of the other, so that whenever ever I click one button then that button should be hidden and the other should be visible, but from the above code the buttons can be kept at a same place but the functionality is not working. Please do suggest.

Comment: Did you remove the inline code? Did you include the jQuery library? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @mplungjan , yes i have included the jQuery library and there are no errors too.

Comment: So what is expected and what actual happend

Comment: @mplungjan The expected is to put two buttons at same place so that if I click play the functionality or the animation should be done and the play button should be hidden, at the same time the pause button should be visible and vice versa. But now whenever I put two buttons at the same position the functionality is not working. It might be because of the two buttons are being clicked as they are in the same position.

Comment: There's a reason they've put a `<button>` tag in HTML. Use it. It will make your code more readable, to both humans and machines.

Comment: This is a bit weird, you're catching onclick AND using jQuery, your setting visibility AND using jQuery... or are you saying that either works on its own? for a starter, you can set one to be hidden by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the CSS for the pause to the script below

[**FIDDLE shows the buttons better**](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tvjc9xoy/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pause").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#play").show();
        $("#aa").stop(true, false);
        audioTag1.pause();
    }).hide(); // hide it initially
    $("#play").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#pause").show();
        animateaa();
    });
});
```

```css
#play { position: relative; border: 3px solid #fff; width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; border-radius: 50%; visibility: hidden; } 
#play:before { position: absolute; left: 14px; top: 10px; content:''; border-left: 12px solid white; border-top: 8px solid transparent; border-right: 8px solid transparent; border-bottom: 8px solid transparent; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: absolute; right: 670px; bottom: 45px;">
    <div id="pause"></div>
    <div id="play"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to take a #css created object as a button.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you want them to replace each other, put them in the same div or have one button and change the html of it

Comment: Yes the above all are satisfying my requirement but i want to use  CSS created buttons as pause and play buttons. so i have used the mentioned code. Is there any possibility by using the CSS created buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by CSS created buttons?

Comment: #play {
    position: relative;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
      width: 36px; 
      height: 36px; 
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50%; 
      visibility: hidden;
      }
 
       #play:before {
       position: absolute;
       left: 14px;
       top: 10px;
       content:'';
       border-left:  12px solid white;
       border-top: 8px solid transparent;
       border-right: 8px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
       }  I have created a button like this and i want this button to be my play button.

Comment: What is stopping you? Add the css for the pause and my modified script will do what you want. I just added the text play/pause to see the actual thing to click when I did not have the CSS

Comment: I am unable to add this CSS created object to <button> tag.

Comment: I do not use button tag

Comment: Yes I will check it out once.

Comment: See the fiddle. It is not working well here because of the absolute position

Comment: In fiddle also it is not showing the output @mplungjan

Comment: And i found another problem after this here. Once I click pause and after that if i click play , then audio file is being played properly where animation part is being played a bit slow.

Comment: It was when I looked. I cannot get to a computer for a few hours. The script works if you fix the css

Comment: I have changed the position in the fiddle. It was very low on the page. It definitely  shows in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/tvjc9xoy/

Comment: The code is perfect and it is working , but here the animation is being played slowly whenever I click pause followed by play. I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I cannot tell you since you did not post the animation part of the script

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest not to use `inline js code` and hide the parent as below:

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 670px; bottom: 45px; display: none;">
    <div id="pause">pause</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 665px; bottom: 45px;">
    <div id="play">play</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pause").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('div').hide();
        $("#play").parents('div').show();
        //$("#aa").stop(true, false);
        //audioTag1.pause();
    });
    $("#play").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('div').hide();
        $("#pause").parents('div').show();
        //animateaa();
    });
});
```

Note: commented function and audio function call as they are missing in OP

Comment: I would use "closest('div')" instead of "parents('div')"

Comment: or better yet just set the ids on the parent div itself

Comment: `closest('div')` will not work, as clicked element will be also a `div` will point to itself

Comment: true, I keep forgetting that and I keep getting into trouble for it :/

Answer (score 1):

here is a way :

html:

```
<div style="position: absolute;"> 

        <div id="pause"><button>pause</button></div>

        <div id="play" style="position:absolute; top:0; display:none;"><button>play</button></div></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pause").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
$("#play").show();
$("#aa").stop(true,false);
audioTag1.pause();
}); 
$("#play").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
$("#pause").show();
animateaa();
}); 
});
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/98cc94nb/

or:

http://jsfiddle.net/98cc94nb/1/

Comment: Do not have inline AND jQuery toggle